# Linux futex syscall spurious wakes with return value 0?

Tags: c, linux, futex

I've run into an issue with the Linux `futex` syscall (`FUTEX_WAIT` operation) sometimes returning early seemingly without cause. The documentation specifies certain conditions that may cause it to return early (without a `FUTEX_WAKE`) but these all involve non-zero return values: `EAGAIN` if the value at the futex address does not match, `ETIMEDOUT` for timed waits that timeout, `EINTR` when interrupted by a (non-restarting) signal, etc. But I'm seeing a return value of 0. What, other than `FUTEX_WAKE` or the termination of a thread whose `set_tid_address` pointer points to the futex, could cause `FUTEX_WAIT` to return with a return value of 0?

In case it's useful, the particular futex I was waiting on is the thread tid address (set by the `clone` syscall with `CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID`), and the thread had **not** terminated. My (apparently incorrect) assumption that the `FUTEX_WAIT` operation returning 0 could only happen when the thread terminated lead to serious errors in program logic, which I've since fixed by looping and retrying even if it returns 0, but now I'm curious as to why it happened.

Here is a minimal test case:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sched.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/futex.h>
#include <signal.h>

static char stack[32768];
static int tid;

static int foo(void *p)
{
        syscall(SYS_getpid);
        syscall(SYS_getpid);
        syscall(SYS_exit, 0);
}

int main()
{
        int pid = getpid();
        for (;;) {
                int x = clone(foo, stack+sizeof stack,
                        CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND
                        |CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM //|CLONE_SETTLS
                        |CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID
                        |CLONE_DETACHED,
                        0, &tid, 0, &tid);
                syscall(SYS_futex, &tid, FUTEX_WAIT, x, 0);
                /* Should fail... */
                syscall(SYS_tgkill, pid, tid, SIGKILL);
        }
}
```

Let it run for a while, at it should eventually terminate with `Killed` (`SIGKILL`), which is only possible if the thread still exists when the `FUTEX_WAIT` returns.

Before anyone goes assuming this is just the kernel waking the futex before it finishes destroying the thread (which might in fact be happening in my minimal test case here), please note that in my original code, I actually observed userspace code running in the thread well after `FUTEX_WAIT` returned.

Comment: I think we may need to see a minimal example; it's hard to come up with substantial advice, since so much is unknown (I'll post my one hunch as a temporary answer anyway, because it's to big for a comment)

Comment: Indeed, I'll see if I can put together a minimal example.

Comment: hm, I think the man page is quite unclear. the conditions under the return value of `FUTEX_WAIT` qualifies the non zero conditions as *error* conditions, not only diagnostics. Then later it says "In the event of an error, all operations return -1, and set errno to indicate the error." On the other hand the conditions here are not repeated in the **ERRORS** section.

Comment: And I just confirmed with `strace` that the "child thread" has not yet called `_exit` when `FUTEX_WAIT` returns.

Comment: It is probably worth asking this on the linux kernel mailing list.

Comment: If you do, please post the answer back here ... I'm curious to know as well ...

Comment: @R.. Did you ever get any answers on this?

Comment: The documentation states that EWOULDBLOCK is returned, not EAGAIN. On most systems these have the same numeric value, but not on SPARC.

Comment: @Jason: No, I didn't follow up much more..

Comment: Hi @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Is this issue still relevant?

Comment: @SomeName: I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Could you be dealing with a race condition between whether the parent or child operations complete first? You can probably investigate this theory by putting small sleeps at the beginning of your foo() or immediately after the clone() to determine if a forced sequencing of events masks the issue. I don't recommend fixing anything in that manner, but it could be helpful to investigate. Maybe the futex isn't ready to be waited upon until the child gets further through its initialization, but the parent's clone has enough to return to the caller?

Specifically, the CLONE_VFORK option's presence seems to imply this is a dangerous scenario. You may need a bi-directional signaling mechanism such that the child signals the parent that it has gotten far enough that it is safe to wait for the child.

Comment: If `tid` had not already been written with the tid value at the time `FUTEX_WAIT` is called, the operation would return with `EAGAIN` rather than 0. (Anyway, the whole point of the `CLONE_PARENT_SETTID` flag to `clone` is to ensure that the value has been written before either thread is able to execute.) I don't see any possibility for a race here in userspace since nothing interesting is happening in userspace...